# Identifying the center of a spiral

Tags: python, spiral

I was looking through an old stackoverflow thread that unravels a spiral. The code does work great, but unfortunately the person who wrote the script hard coded key values like where the center of the spiral is.

[How to unroll the drawing of a spiral?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681397/how-to-unroll-the-drawing-of-a-spiral?newreg=af8e6abde7e64b6e847d7a6d7b1bd78b)

Is there a way to identify what the coordinates of the center of a spiral is?
[Example Spiral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUJu8.png)

If adding a marker is the only way, that will suffice but ideally it would be without introducing markers.

I've tried markers, but that solution isn't ideal. Since this spiral will be unraveled later and then analyzed as a discrete signal, I ideally don't want markers in the center of the image (they can be outside the spiral though for all i care).

i tried a Hough Transform to identify contours and then trace those contours back to the center, but I'm not that good of a programmer to figure something that complex out.

i also tried this code but as i said, it hardcodes the center instead of identifying it:
[How to unroll the drawing of a spiral?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681397/how-to-unroll-the-drawing-of-a-spiral?newreg=af8e6abde7e64b6e847d7a6d7b1bd78b)

The images are going to be scanned images so they won't have the same center each time.

Comment: Maybe this can help in some way https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336962/how-to-find-the-center-of-a-log-spiral